# Laravel: Move files from local server to Production server and I am getting this error open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server

I successfully uploaded my Laravel app to my server and when I checked my site. I got this error

> file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RPI/storage/logs/laravel-2019-12-15.log)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/isky.io\;C:\Windows\Temp)

After that I changed the file name which is in bootstrap/cache according to this link please have a look at this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/is-dir-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect 
ok now my home page is loaded but when I click on login button now I am getting this error again

> file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\i-skyhr.io\RPI\resources\lang/en/Forgot
>   Password?.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/i-skyhr.io\;C:\Windows\Temp) (View:
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\i-skyhr.io\RPI\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

please help I don't know why I am getting this error

Comment: try ```composer du``` in your root

Comment: facing same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the cache and config, then deploy to the live server. Please try the following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

If you've already uploaded to the live server, then you have to follow these steps:

1. Delete bootstrap/cache/config.php
2. Delete all log files in
   storage/logs.